# Will new HDD improve PC performances

Tags: hard-drive, speed

I'm curious about why my PC gets unuseable after closing bigger apps/games. For example, it takes almost one minute to close The Division game. After closing the game, screen stays Black for next half to one minute, but when it finally close, PC become useable.
Next example is Fortnite(don't hate me). It closes really fast but for next one minute PC is unuseable, everything loads so slow, music app doesn't responde etc…
After I log in in my account(for First time after start-up) PC become unuseable until three programs start up(OneDrive client, Radeon Settings and FxSound).
If I'm instaling/updating something PC is unuseable.

My configuration:

1. **CPU:** Intel Q9400
2. **HDD:** 500GB (Full name: `WDC WD5000AAKS-00UU3A0`)
3. **MBO:** Asus P5G41T-M LX2/GB
4. **RAM:** 8GB 1333MHz
5. **GPU:** AMD R7 260x
6. **OS:** Windows 10 1809

So my question is - Does new HDD(don't have enough Money for SSD) will improve PC loading performaces? Does HDD really matters a lot? I Know HDD will never be fast like SSD. Current HDD is sever years old. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A computer should not become "unusable" after closing an application.  There is something wrong with it.

Comment: @Keltari My English isn't good so I'm "limited" with words. PC becomes unusable how slow it becomes. I hope you understand now.

Comment: If you don't need a ton of space - there's fairly reasonably priced, smaller SSDs you can use alongside your current hard drive - OS on say a 120 gb drive. That said, it feels like a really odd build. Its a pretty great processor from a decade ago... a midrange modern video card...

Comment: Need space for OS(200+ GB) + space for games. I now build is odd. I use PC for almost everything, programing, Cad/cam, graphic design and little bit for gaming(few games)

Comment: Some of the problem could be related to use of OneDrive, which transfers data over the internet. Another possible cause is that the page file is sized incorrectly for 8GB RAM. Finally, use Task Manager to check both Disk I/O and CPU use while you attempt to close and restart a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current hard drive is not damaged or > 80% full, it is unlikely that a new hard drive will make a significant difference because the drives still need to wait for platters to spin under the heads and rotation speeds have not changed much.  If the problem is your hard drive (and you may be able to tell by correlating slowdowns with activity on a disk light), then the issue is most likely related to swap/virtual memory.

You may be able to get some benefit by de-fragmenting your hard drive.

Also, SSD's have fallen dramatically in price over the last few months. Amazon and Newegg both sell decent quality 500 gig(Samsung 850/860) gig SSD's for < $80 now.  120 gig SSD drives are cheaper then 500 gig hard drives now, and if used as a boot, OS and swap drive, will make a significant difference.

Comment: Need over 200+ GB for system drive so SSDs are out.

Comment: My initial post ate the bit that said it's  that its new *500 gig SSDs* for less then US$80.

Comment: SSDs help programs load faster, especially modern games. After an overnight checkdisk and a defrag of your HDD, check the size of your still slow programs and look for an affordable SSD to reinstall them on. You can simply add it to your system, but may require a separate SATA cable and/or tray.

Comment: @ceez timmerman you also want to makes sure that it is the program that is slow and not system resources like swap.

Comment: @davidgo Swap is terrible, even with an SSD. 8 GB should be enough for Chrome with The Great Discarder or Quake Champions, not both unless the GPU has extra RAM.

Comment: @ceestimmerman -  *Excessive* swap is bad, but even there an SSD will be many orders if magnitude faster, a previous 30 sec is bottleneck will decrease to a lot less then 6 secs.  In my (Linux based) world, a small amount of swap is desireable so that (a) your programs don't suddenly die by running out of memory and (b) to maximise resource use by putting important but rarely used (kernel/driver) routines on swap. I posit the same will be true on Windows.

Comment: I'll try with 250GB 860 EVO. Thanks guys for help!